# rapidjson - change object - add element/item

Tags: c++, json, element, addition, rapidjson

how do I add a member to a rapidjson object and then print it?

for example add

```
 itemtwo => "world" ;
```

to this object:

```
{"itemone":"hello"}
```

I tried

```
 char buff[] = "{\"itemone\":\"hello\"}";
 rapidjson::Document json_obj;
 if(json_obj.Parse<0>(buff.c_str()).HasParseError() == false){        
    json_obj["itemtwo"].SetString("world");
    rapidjson::StringBuffer strbuf;
    rapidjson::Writer<rapidjson::StringBuffer> writer(strbuf);
    json_obj.Accept(writer);
    cout<<strbuf.GetString()<<endl;
 }
```

I get the following output:

```
{"itemone":"hello"}
```

meaning no change.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

`json_obj["itemtwo"]` can only find member with that name, which is not exist. It does not create a new entry (as in `std::map`).

To manipulate objects, use `AddMember()` and other related member functions, e.g.

```
json_obj.AddMember("itemone", "hello", json_obj.GetAllocator());
```

You may refer to [rapidjson user guide](https://code.google.com/p/rapidjson/wiki/UserGuide) and/or the tutorial.cpp in the package.